# I have issue with the network config file caliper_config.yaml

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

its for Peer-to-Peer Energy Trading in Smart Grid Through Blockchain: A Double Auction-Based Game Theoretic Approach ,i have a repo that i want to run with FABRIC and CALIPER but i have issue with the network config file caliper_config.yaml,if someone can help please

this is the repo https://github.com/hiengithub/A-Double-Auction-Based-Game-Theoretic-Approach.git, the file caliper_config.yaml doesnt existe and i need to create it from scratch ,any idea how ?